# maximum value in php array for each key value

Tags: php

I want to find out the maximum value of the each key in the array

```
$arr1= array(
    0=>array(1,2,3),
    1=>array(2,4,6),
    2=>array(25,4,5));
}
```

I want to find the maximum value for each value for the corresponding key
The final output shuld be

```
$max_array = array(25,4,6);
```

with the below code i get error  max(): When only one parameter is given, it must be an array in

```
foreach ($res_arr as $k=>$subArray) {
    foreach ($subArray as $id=>$value) {
        $spanmaxArray[$id] = max($value);
    }
}
```

Comment: that is corrected.comparing the [0],[1][2] the first element 1,2,25.The max valus is 25,same way for other elements also.the return value should be also an array.

Comment: [Bob's your uncle](https://eval.in/private/a5f164f663cce8). Read the manual !

Comment: @HamZa I think he wants to output the max for each column

Comment: @MarioJohnathan Ah I see, `array_column()` might be handy (PHP 5.5+). [demo](https://eval.in/private/f17ca3630660b4)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, rotate array to makes columns as lines

```
$arr1= array(
    0=>array(1,2,3),
    1=>array(2,4,6),
    2=>array(25,4,5)
);

$arr2 = array();

foreach($arr1 as $subArray) {
    foreach($subArray as $k=>$v) {
        $arr2[$k][] = $v;
    }
}
```

Then, use array_map as @HamZa did

```
$max_array  = array_map('max', $arr2);
print_r($max_array);
```

Comment: Spot on answer. Works well!

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach ($res_arr as $k=>$subArray){
        $max = 0;
        foreach ($subArray as $id=>$value){
            if ($value>$max){
                $max = $value;
            }
        }
        $spanmaxArray[$k] = $max;
}
```

Try this.

Answer (score 2):

Definitely the shortest version:

```
$max_array = array_map('max', $arr1);
```

array_map() takes each element array of $arr1 and applies max() to it.

Edited after seeing that max in each column position is desired:

```
$sorted = array();
for ($i = 0; $i <=2; $i++) { 
    $sorted[$i] = array_column($input, $i);
}
```

This loops over the array and applies array_column() to each (requires PHP 5.5).

So:

```
$sorted = array();
for ($i = 0; $i <=2; $i++) { 
    $sorted[$i] = array_column($arr1, $i);
}
$max_array = array_map('max', $sorted);
```

[working version](https://eval.in/private/701f239665e009)

Comment: OP wanted to get the max of each column so @Mario Johnathan's answer is better.

Answer (score 0):

You only need one loop, because the max function takes an array as a parameter. But the answer you are giving is wrong, unless I've misunderstood the problem.

I think what you're after is:

```
$max_array = array_map('max', $arr1);
```

Answer (score 0):

All of the earlier answers are working too hard.

- Use `array_map()` as the iterating function.
- Unpack your multidimensional array with the "spread/splat operator" (`...`); in other words, convert your single array containing three subarrays into three separate arrays.
- Call `max()` on the three elements as they are synchronously iterated by `array_map()`.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/ovbga))

```
$arr1 = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [2, 4, 6],
    [25, 4, 5],
];

var_export(array_map('max', ...$arr1));
```

The above is a more versatile and concise version of the following one-liner which has the same effect on the sample array:

```
var_export(array_map('max', $arr1[0], $arr1[1], $arr1[2]));
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 25,
  1 => 4,
  2 => 6,
)
```

*A note for researchers: if processing a multidimensional array that has associative first level keys, you will need to index the first level so that the splat operator doesn't choke on the keys.

```
...array_values($array)
```